# Ground track's equations for latitude and longitude?

Tags: orbital-motion

I've been having trouble finding equations to calculate latitude and longitude in books or other materials. I want to understand how they are mathematically expressed and attempt to use them with the ISS to create my own ground track. The only equation I'm familiar with (though I'm not sure if it's correct) is for latitude:

= arcsin (sin () ⋅ sin ( + v) )

Where:

i is the inclination,

ω is the argument of perigee, and

v is the true anomaly.

Does anyone know the equations or recommend any good books or resources on how to derive or calculate them?

Having the TLE info, I can calculate the Eccentric anomaly and then I would like to calculate latitude and longitude